# If statement variable assignment in batch file ignored

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

I am new to batch file coding and am trying to write a simple If-Else statement.

I have tried to use delayedexpansion as suggested in other questions but still don't seem to get the right value

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET VAR=portrait
IF %VAR% == portrait do (
    SET /a height=1920;
    set /a width=1080;
) else do(
    set /a height=1080;
    set /a width=1920;
)

echo %height%
```

The code above gives the output as 1080, while I am expecting 1920 based on the logic I wrote. Can someone please help me understand?

Comment: Your example is not working. If you'll fix all syntactic errors it will work as expected.

Comment: I didn’t get any syntax error when I ran this. I do get an output. Are you getting an error?

Comment: Have you tried this exact example? Mind `do` and semi-colons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You issue is mainly because there's no such thing as an `If / Do` or `Else / Do` statement. Also you should try to remember that `Set /A` is really for arithmetic, and you're not doing math, just setting values to names.

```bat
If "%VAR%" == "portrait" (
    Set "height=1920"
    Set "width=1080"
) Else (
    Set "height=1080"
    Set "width=1920"
)
Echo %height%
```

However, you can in this case, still use `Set /A` to shorten your commands a little; because `Set /A` allows for multiple names to integer values within the same statement.

```bat
If "%VAR%" == "portrait" (
   Set /A height=1920, width=1080
) Else (
   Set /A height=1080, width=1920
)
Echo %height%
```